# ORACLE PL/SQL Error with Stored Procedure while consulting information from 3 columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I created a Stored procedure in order to retrieve some information from 3 columns. I can compile it with no errors but when I do the `EXEC` I get an error:

```
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
```

Here is the PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE consult_employee(
e_id IN OUT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
e_nom   OUT EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
e_job   OUT EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID%TYPE
) IS
BEGIN
-- Consult the employee
SELECT employee_id, first_name, job_id
INTO e_id, e_nom, e_job
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id = e_id;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your consult is: ' || e_id || e_nom || e_job);
END;
```

When i execute the next, I get the error:

```
EXEC consult_employee(102);
```

And this is what's on my table:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | JOB_ID
____________|____________|________
    102     |    Lex     | AD_VP
```

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure expects three parameters but you're only passing one. And all three of the parameters you pass should be variables, not constants, because they're either IN OUT or OUT parameters.

So you should be doing something like:

```
DECLARE
  nEmp_id        NUMBER := 102;
  strFirst_name  VARCHAR2(100);
  nJob_id        NUMBER;
BEGIN
  CONSULT_EMPLOYEE(nEmp_id, strFirst_name, nJob_id);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP_ID=' || nEmp_id ||
                       '  FIRST_NAME=''' || strFirst_name || '''' ||
                       '  JOB_ID=' || nJob_id);
END;
```

Best of luck